# Is switch operator atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

In documentation it is said you could equally use `if-else` multiple times or `switch-case`:

```
int condition;

setCondition(int condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}
```

Either switch-case

```
switch (condition) {
  case 1: print("one"); break;
  case 2: print("two"); break;
```

or

```
if (condition == 1) { print("one"); }
else if (condition == 2) { print("two"); }
```

Next, `condition`is declared `volatile` and method `setCondition()` is called from multiple threads.
`If-else` is not atomic and `volatile` variable write is a synchronizing action. So both "one" and "two" string could be printed in the last code.

It could be avoided if some method local variable with initial value was used:

```
int localCondition = condition;
if (local condition == ..) ..
```

Does `switch-case` operator hold some initial copy of variable? How are cross threads operations implemented with it?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: If/else guarantees that only one branch is taken even in the face of race conditions. This would only be possible in languages like c where a race condition causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Boris The whole point of `if/else if` comapred to `if/if` is that that's not the case.

Comment: @Voo I see your point - I'm being thick. Blame it on the Sunday hangover. I suppose it could print _nothing_ if the value changes during evaluation however - which is the race condition that `switch` would prevent.

Comment: In **which** documentation does it illustrate multiple if-else versus switch-case? Maybe it is an informal piece of documentation that covers the language basics but not the subtleties of multithreading

Comment: in defense of @Voo's hangover, he asserted that "`if/else` guarantees that [exactly] one branch is taken even in the face of race conditions," which is in no way untrue. The follow-up addressing `if/else if` versus `if/if`, while perhaps tangentially related, doesn't alter the claim as stated.

Comment: @Boris Happens to the best of us :-) But yes that could certainly happen - but the same thing would be possible with a switch depending on the implementation strategy chosen by the JVM (basically it's perfectly valid to implement a switch as a cascade of if/else if - and that's often enough the most efficient implementation!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) on switch statements:

> When the switch statement is executed, first the Expression is evaluated. [...]

This *suggests* that the expression is evaluated once and that the result is temporarily kept somewhere else, and so no race-conditions are possible.

I can't find a definite answer anywhere though.

---

A quick test shows this is indeed the case:

```
public class Main {
  private static int i = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    switch(sideEffect()) {
      case 0:
        System.out.println("0");
        break;
      case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("something else");
    }

    System.out.println(i); //this prints 1
  }

  private static int sideEffect() {
    return i++;
  }
}
```

And indeed, sideEffect() is only called once.

Comment: Think of it another way: If we wrote `switch(someFunctionWithSideEffect())`, then the switch statement had better evaluate that function *exactly once*

Comment: @Todd Sewell "...the Expression is evaluated..." does not suggest anything. It means that the Expression is evaluated [according to the specifications of the JVM], meaning that the implementer of the Expression evaluator for a given JVM must not break volatile access rules. As such, it should be subject to the same conditions of the currently executing Thread.

Comment: +1. Oddly, although the spec does define the nouns "read" and "write" and so on, it doesn't really go into detail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2. But aside from the special cases of `long` and `double`, it seems that they're supposed to mean exactly what you'd naively expect; for example, it seems clear that something like `int foo = this.mFoo; return foo + foo;` is only allowed to perform *one* "read" of `this.mFoo`.

Comment: I'm not a Java person, but the topic here is called the language's formal [memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) (if it has one). These are the guarantees the language makes about memory access which, as noted here, become important--nay essential--for correctness given concurrency.

Comment: @Glenn Slayden, java has memory model (see JMM), and I thought the questing was about it. But as far as switch() uses local variable (evaluated expression value) this question seems not to be in JMM scope.
See Shipilev's lecture on JMM: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/
"the memory models appear to answer a simple question: "What values can a particular read observe?""

Answer (score 14):

The expression is evaluated *once* when entering the switch.

The switch may *use* the result internally as many times as it needs to determine what code to jump to. It's akin to:

```
int switchValue = <some expression>;
if (switchValue == <some case>)
    <do something>
else if (switchValue == <some other case>
    <do something else>
// etc
```

Actually, a switch compiles to a variety of byte code styles depending on the number of cases and the type of the value.

The switch only needs to evaluate the expression once.

Comment: is this true if the expression (and case labels) is a String?

Comment: @carlos yes. Strings are immutable. Once you have a reference to a switch's String expression, it's effectively a constant

Comment: @Bohemian If your claim is "from x follows y" but x is untrue, the whole explanation is suspect. Yes the switch can only have one true branch but that's because the JLS requires it, not because jump tables are involved (because in practice there are no jump tables in the vast majority of switches). But yes I deleted my comment because I wanted to make this clearer. In general explaining contractual behaviour with implementation details is incredibly dangerous (particularly lots of broken concurrent code can be traced back to that)

Comment: just the "The switch only needs to use the expression once" that has confused me: the value of the expression is used twice for Strings, but only calculated once...

Comment: @voo Fine... I've swapped out by answer's implementation with a different one (similar to what `switch` can do.

Comment: @Carlos I've modified my answer. Hopefully it is less confusing now.

Comment: @ruakh OK. I've simplified my answer and removed the offending portion...